# What is the difference between common_funny and funny_files from filecmp.dircmp?

Tags: python

The filecmp module from the standard library contains a the [dircmp class](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/filecmp.html#the-dircmp-class) which has two similar sounding attribues:

**common_funny:**

> Names in both a and b, such that the type differs between the
>   directories, or names for which os.stat() reports an error.

**funny_files:**

> Files which are in both a and b, but could not be compared.

What would cause files or directories to appear in common_funny?
What would cause files or directories to appear in funny_files?

Comment: I assume the implementation is the same for Python 2.x and 3.x. Please le me know if this is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Use the source Luke](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.2/Lib/filecmp.py).

`common_funny` gets appended to if the types of the two files don't match (eg one is a file, the other a directory), or it isn't a recognised type, or the os.stat blew up.  These are returned in the first pass when just looking at file names and types.

`funny_files` is made from files which `dircmp` thought it could compare, but couldn't read for some reason - some kind of os.error on reading maybe (permission denied for instance).  These are returned in the second pass when actually trying to see the differences in the files (when actually running `filecmp.cmp`).

I didn't know about the [filecmp module](http://docs.python.org/library/filecmp.html) - thanks for bringing it to my attention!